# Anchor Option is not showing in Admin

Tags: category-attribute, ce-1.9.1.1

I'm experiencing this issue with Magento 1.9.1 single store,

probably my database got damaged:

When I edit an existing category or add a new one the option to select if the category is anchored or not is not appearing

[image]

I have backups of some days ago but if there is another way to recover that would be better.

In the frontend some categories still have the layered navigation even if in the admin area I can't choose whether to enable it or not.

Comment: You could restore just that DB table only to rectify? What have you edited or changed in the last few days that could have possibly created the issue?

Comment: I've installed this module [link](https://github.com/Smile-SA/smile-magento-elasticsearch) and now that I check the setup I see this ` $installer->updateAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'is_anchor', 'frontend_input', 'hidden');
$installer->updateAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'is_anchor', 'default_value', 1); ` so I try to investigate how to revert that

Comment: Yes, that'll be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it. Basic you need change the `frontend_input` and `default_value` columns of `in_anchor` attribute.
There are two ways to do it.

**1. Create a module to do it**

You can create a extension to create/edit attributes category following this tutorial: http://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/

To fix `is_anchor` attribute, you need this:

```
$installer->updateAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'is_anchor', 'frontend_input', 'select'); 
$installer->updateAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'is_anchor', 'default_value', NULL);
```

**2. Change values direct in database**

```
 UPDATE `DATABASE_HERE`.`eav_attribute` SET `frontend_input`='select', `default_value`='NULL' WHERE `attribute_id`='51';
```

NOTE: Check attribute_id of `is_anchor` and replace if necessary (in my case it's 51).

NOTE2: Be careful and do a backup before!!!

Comment: I did the second suggestion and good enough for that. Thanks